# How to add a new column with key information in that column from dictionary of different length array without loosing any value in pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, numpy

Input

```
dict_table = {'Table1': [1, 2,], 'Table2': [3, 4, 5], 'Table3': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

Result

| Table_name | Table_value | New_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Table1 | 1 | Table1 |
| Table1 | 2 | Table1 |
| Table2 | 3 | Table2 |
| Table2 | 4 | Table2 |
| Table2 | 5 | Table2 |
| Table3 | 6 | Table3 |
| Table3 | 7 | Table3 |
| Table3 | 8 | Table3 |
| Table3 | 9 | Table3 |
| Table3 | 10 | Table3 |
| Table3 | 11 | Table3 |

Comment: please don't change the formatting anymore, we fixed it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result from the dictionary using:

```
out = (pd.Series(dict_table).explode()
         .rename_axis('Table_name').reset_index(name='Table_value')
       )
```

Or:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([[k, v] for k, l in dict_table.items() for v in l],
                   columns=['Table_name', 'Table_value'])
```

Output:

```
   Table_name Table_value
0      Table1           1
1      Table1           2
2      Table2           3
3      Table2           4
4      Table2           5
5      Table3           6
6      Table3           7
7      Table3           8
8      Table3           9
9      Table3          10
10     Table3          11
```